# Wix CustomAction Grouping

Tags: xml, wix, grouping

Is it possible to have a "wrapper" tag of sorts, to group together many `<CustomAction>` statements (so they can be folded away in an editor)?  The Oracle hasn't responded favourably to my inquiry on the matter, but I might be asking the wrong question...

Comment: you can group them in a <Fragment > or add them to separate  wxi file or initialize them just before  <InstallExecuteSequence>

Comment: Wrapping with Fragment didn't work, VS tells me "The Directory element contains an unexpected child element 'fragment'." Actually, that was from one I placed higher up, to consolidate a bunch of drivers.  The CustomAction defs being wrapped in Fragment complains similarly about the Product element.

Comment: that is because you should initialize <Fragment> after the end of your </Product> no ?